# Does non linear transform of Gaussain Random Variables results in Gaussian?

Tags: probability, gaussian-elimination

I have a question, if we do a non linear transformation on Gaussian random vector, will it give us Gaussian as a result? If No which techniques can we use to make sure the result is finally gaussian.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Take $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$. Then $X^2$ has the chi-squared distribution with $1$ degree of freedom.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Does Jacobian help us in someway to make the transformation linear?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, if the transformation $g$ is nonlinear, then $g(X)$ is in general not Gaussian.  (Practically any nonlinear $g$ will give you an immediate counterexample.)

But if $g$ is smooth enough (so that locally it is approximately linear), and the variance of $X$ is small (so that its values are concentrated in a small neighborhood), then the distribution of $g(X)$ will be approximately Gaussian.  This is a special case of the [delta method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method), which you can read for a precise statement.  The Jacobian of $g$ will help compute the variance of $g(X)$.